# MHTabBarController add to uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Im trying to use the MHTabBarController https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController
, in the example the custom view controller is added as a rootViewController in app delegate,
i want to add 3 tabs inside a standard tab bar controller's view for example MainViewController
here is my code inside viewDidLoad in MainViewController.m:

```
//MHTabBarController config
ListViewController *listViewController1 = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
ListViewController *listViewController2 = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
ListViewController *listViewController3 = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

listViewController1.title = @"Tab 1";
listViewController2.title = @"Tab 2";
listViewController3.title = @"Tab 3";


NSArray *viewControllers = @[listViewController1, listViewController2, listViewController3];
MHTabBarController *tabBarController = [[MHTabBarController alloc] init];

tabBarController.delegate = self;
tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

ive also added the  in MainViewController.h
but its not working, its showing a table but not the tabs on top.
what im missing?

Answer (score 0):

That code should go inside the AppDelegate.m

Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

   mainViewController.title = @"Main Tab";

   NSArray *viewControllers = @[mainViewController];

   MHTabBarController *tabBarController = [[MHTabBarController alloc] init];

   tabBarController.delegate = self;
   tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

This way you're adding a the tab bar into the MainViewController, if you wanna add the same tab bar into other view controllers, just add the view controllers into the viewControllers array.